# Curl request from command line and via Groovy script

Tags: curl, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing an issue which i do not understand, I have written a simple groovy script that when called from the command line works as expected

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def jsonParse(def json) {
  new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(json)
}

def ticketNumbers = ["MYSTATS-2695", "MYSTATS-2694"]

 ArrayList<String> jiraLinks = new ArrayList<String>();

  for(int i =0; i < ticketNumbers.size(); i++) {
    def jira_json = "curl -o /dev/null -X GET -H Content-Type: application/json --cert-type PEM --key-type PEM -E /Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/certificates/cert.pem --key /Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/certificates/cert.pem https://jira.dev.org.co.uk:443/rest/api/2/issue/${ticketNumbers[i]}".execute().text;
    def json = jsonParse(jira_json);
    def summary = json['fields']['summary'].toString();
    jiraLinks.add("[" + ticketNumbers[i] + "](https://jira.dev.org.co.uk/browse/" + ticketNumbers[i] + ")" + " - " + summary);
  }

 println "${jiraLinks}"
```

so when i do `groovy myscript.groovy`

This will print out

```
[[MYSTATS-2695 ](https://jira.dev.org.co.uk/browse/MYSTATS-2695 ) - Jenkins build pipeline should ignore draft and pre-releases, [MYSTATS-2694 ](https://jira.dev.org.co.uk/browse/MYSTATS-2694 ) - Android Jenkins pipeline should populate the comscore SDK version automatically]
```

So that is as expected.

What i then have is a groovy script which i call as part of a jenkins pipeline build

```
class Helpers {

   def jsonParse(def json) {
     new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(json)
   }

  def createJiraLinks(def ticketNumbers) {

    ArrayList<String> jiraLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i =0; i < ticketNumbers.size(); i++) {
      def jira_json = "/usr/bin/curl -o /dev/null -X GET -H Content-Type: application/json --cert-type PEM --key-type PEM -E /Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/certificates/cert.pem --key /Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/certificates/cert.pem https://jira.dev.org.co.uk:443/rest/api/2/issue/MYSTATS-2695".execute().text;
      def json = jsonParse(jira_json);
      def summary = json['fields']['summary'].toString();
    jiraLinks.add("[" + ticketNumbers[i] + "](https://jira.dev.org.co.uk/browse/" + ticketNumbers[i] + ")" + " - " + summary);
    }
    return jiraLinks;
  }

}
return new Helpers();
```

As part of my Jenkins build i have

```
def groovyMethod = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/groovy_scripts/release_pipeline.groovy")
def jira = groovyMethod.createJiraLinks(ticketNumberCommits);
echo "JIRA LINKAS ARE $jira"
// $jira is always returned as empty string
```

Am i misunderstanding anything here as i would have expected this to work? but it seems as if the curl request never gets anything back

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

groovy String.execute() returns [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) that could be still running (depends on system load and weather))

if you want to wait until process ended do like this:

```js
    def txt = "cmd /c dir c:\\".execute().with{
        def output = new StringWriter()
        def error = new StringWriter()
        //wait for process ended and catch stderr and stdout 
        it.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
        //check there is no error
        assert error.toString().size()==0: "$error"
        //println it.exitValue() //we can do check with error code
        //return stdout from closure 
        return output.toString()
    }
```

for `jenkins pipeline` to avoid error `java.io.NotSerializableException`
use the following code:

```js
    node {
        def res = runAndWait("cmd /c dir c:\\")
        echo res
    }
    
    @NonCPS
    String runAndWait(Object cmd){
        def proc = cmd.execute()
        def output = new StringWriter()
        def error = new StringWriter()
        //wait for process ended and catch stderr and stdout 
        proc.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
        //check there is no error
        assert error.toString().trim().size()==0: "$error"
        //assert proc.exitValue()==0 //we can do check with error code
        //return stdout from closure 
        return output.toString()
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i get `java.lang.AssertionError: curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'`, i was not getting this error before so is this because of the code you provided ?

Comment: that's exactly because of this check: `assert error.toString().size()==0: "$error"`. if stderror was not empty, it throws exception with stderror text.

Comment: cool, thanks.Can you see any issues with the way my curl request is constructed as it is timing out and not connecting to the endpoint specified (the one in the post is a dummy one but even if i replace it with say google it does not connect)

Comment: yes, just quote the header `... -H 'Content-Type: application/json' ...`

Comment: i still get `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'` what i dont understand is that if i run this via the command line like `groovy test.groovy` it works, fails when run as part of the jenkins pipeline though

Comment: ah so i quoted the url and now i get back `curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Comment: Long time since your answer but this helped me finally output the json from my curl command in the Jenkins Script Console. Thank you!