# Groovy Execute Bash Script in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to run a bash script from Groovy in Jenkins but I am not able to find the lucky commands.

I can run this and it creates my "RJ" directory:

```
process = "mkdir /app/jenkins/workspace/TEST/RJ"
println process.execute()
```

But when I try to run my bash it is not creating my output file.  I am able to run this bash script on the server directly and it is creating my expected output file.

```
process = "/app/jenkins/workspace/TEST/info_file.sh"
println process.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

why run it through groovy and not directly via a ssh command.

If you do want to do via groovy, you'll need to add a ssh libray, and do the whole connection, auth, execute. process.execute won't run a linux box.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Peter.  That stinks and this is on Linux too.  The goal is to use the "Active Reactive Parameter Plugin".  When I select a value from an "Active Choice Parameter" (selecting a server) I would like code to run a script on that selected server to read a file and pull in an array of values.  This would be ideal because we would then be reading the source every time.  Option 2 is to create a process to read the files on the remote servers and have the list of values locally.

Comment: Your running this through jenkins right? Create a user defined variable, and drop down, that has to be set before a build kicks off. When you press play, this drop will show and you select which server. The ssh task then executes what ever, you then save the results of the execution somewhere locally, then parse the file.

Answer (score 0):

first, you don't check the stderr and not waiting for process to end.

similar problem was here:

[Curl request from command line and via Groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372447/curl-request-from-command-line-and-via-groovy-script/44383995#44383995)

with error text it's easier to solve the error.