# Groovy executing mvn command

Tags: linux, shell, maven, groovy

I'm writing groovy script and trying to execute following shell command using execute() method

```
"mvn clean install -f \{pom directory}\pom.xml".execute()
```

but got an error with following message

"Cannot run program "mvn": error=2, No such file or directory"

Of course, maven is already installed and the command works well on terminal....

I also tried with "sc -c" prefix.

```
"sh -c mvn clean install -f \<pom directory\pom.xml".execute()
```

But this does execute nothing and no error at all. it seems like the command just ignored.

So how should I execute maven install in groovy script?

Comment: Did you try `"/complete/path/to/mvn ..."`?

Comment: what is your operation system? windows or linux? i'm asking because you try to use sh and specifying path with backslashes. on linux path should be specified like this `/<pom directory/pom.xml`. Also you have to catch output to understand the result. Check this example how to execute and wait for result:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372447/curl-request-from-command-line-and-via-groovy-script/44383995#44383995

Comment: and finally, you would use double backslash in a string to escape the backslash from escaping the next character... Which is why forward slash is so much better in paths and works on both platforms.

Comment: did you find out how to execute this via groovyscript?

Answer (score 1):

Since `mvn` is not an executable binary but a shell script, it cannot be directly
executed.

This is also related to your second case where you execute `sh -c ...`.  I suspect that the environment is not properly configured.  In this case the output is written to stderr which is the reason you see no output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799111/unable-to-capture-full-output-from-groovy-execute) on how to capture stderr.

I had this issue in a groovy script executed by Jenkins.  In this situation you can for example use `sh 'mvn --version'` and everything is working.  The `sh` is from the Jenkins DSL.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, mvn is not an exe-file but a command (mvn.cmd).
I fixed the issue the following way:

```
def cmd = ""
if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
    println "On Windows mvn is a CMD and not an EXE"
    cmd = "mvn.cmd wrapper:wrapper"
} else {
    println "Execute just the mvn executable on non Windows systems"
    cmd = "mvn wrapper:wrapper"
}
def process = cmd.execute(null, rootDir)
process.waitForProcessOutput((Appendable)System.out, System.err)
if (process.exitValue() != 0) {
    println "WARNING: Command '$cmd' exited with code: ${process.exitValue()}"
    println "WARNING: you can initialize the maven wrapper by yourself:}"
    println "WARNING: go to $rootDir and type in 'mvn wrapper:wrapper'}"
}
```