# How to execute a svn checkout in a Jenkins Pipeline in a Groovy file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cmd, jenkins-pipeline, svn-checkout

I have a script in groovy and I need to execute a svn Checkout. Here's what I have :

---

```
"cmd /c \"svn checkout PATHtoSVN PATHtoDIRECTORY\"".execute()
```

---

But it doesn't work. Can someone help me ? 
Thx.

Comment: what does it happen? is svn command in path?

Comment: It's `['cmd', '-c', 'svn checking...'].execute()`

Comment: I'm loading a classfile in jenkins and one of those classes contains a checkout, so the error in jenkins is 'java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector'. The svn command is Checkout.

Comment: ['cmd', '-c', 'svn checking...'].execute() gives me the same error.

Comment: the error you mentioned `java.io.NotSerializableException` appeared under jenkins pipeline. if it so, please modify your question and add tags `jenkins` and `jenkins-pipeline`

Comment: I've tried lauching a batch file with my checkout inside, but it seems that the slave can't execute the batch script.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372447/curl-request-from-command-line-and-via-groovy-script/44383995#44383995

Comment: I'm still getting the same error (java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector) and I'm using your function runAndWait(Object cmd).

Answer (score 0):

Emile, why don't you try to use the general checkout step in your pipeline code?

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', locations: [[credentialsId: 'svn-server', local: '.', remote: '<SVN URL>']]])
```

See https://JENKINS_SERVER_HOSTNAME/job/PIPELINE_NAME/pipeline-syntax/ for full step syntax.

Please mind that the `svn` Step is easier but does not allow to specify potentially needed credentials...

Comment: I can't do it in my Pipeline, because I want to do my checkout inside a class.

Comment: Inside a class of e.g. a shared Jenkins library would allow using such steps too.