# Groovy script to download script and run it with parameters

Tags: perl, jenkins, groovy

Need help with groovy script.

We have a perl script in github. We need to download and run the perl-script inside groovy script (jenkins) and also pass parameters to the script and get the output.

Example, Perl script in github accepts parameter "item1" "item2", using curl we get the raw format of the script.

---

```
def command = "curl -s https://github.com/raw/script.pl?token=%3D"
def proc = command.execute() | "perl /dev/stdin $item1 $item2".execute()
proc.waitFor()
def roles = []
roles = "${proc.in.text}" .eachLine { line ->
    roles << line
}
return roles
```

---

Above script does not return expected result. Please help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What result does it return? Or is there any error message?

Comment: this returns default error on jenkins..

Comment: Just put the error in the question, so that others with same question may find them.

Comment: Also tried -  def url= "https://github.com/raw/script.pl?3D"
def command = [ 'perl', "curl ${url}" "item1" "item2"].execute()
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
def roles = []
roles = "${proc.in.text}" .eachLine { line ->
    roles << line
}
return roles ..... But it doesnot work. However if I try following on shell , the perl script works well SHELL> curl -s https://github.com/raw/script.pl?token=D | perl /dev/stdin item1 item2

Comment: `proc.in` - is a process input stream, but you are reading from it - so i think you need an out stream... check this how to read the output for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372447/curl-request-from-command-line-and-via-groovy-script/44383995#44383995

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys. Found it. Actually following does work..

```
def command = "curl -s https://github.com/raw/script.pl?token=%3D"
def proc = command.execute() | "perl /dev/stdin $item1 $item2".execute()
proc.waitFor()
def roles = []
roles = "${proc.in.text}" .eachLine { line ->
    roles << line
}
return roles
```

Comment: Groovy supports loading resources via a url directly. I.e. `https://github.com/raw/script.pl.toUrl().text` would remove the `curl` dependency. 
If you need a stream.. use `.openStream()` instead of `.text`.

Comment: `"${proc.in.text}" ` could be simplified to `proc.in.text.eachLine {..`